# Converting a Xamarin.forms iOS app into Xcode app

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.forms

I am having a problem but can't seem to find the much-needed information online, having trawled through the internet. I have Xamarin.forms iOS app that I want to test. I cannot run iOS in windows so transferred to mac.

To inspect elements in the app, I need to open the app in Xcode or appium inspector, so I created an Xcode project from the source control containing the Xamarin.forms iOS app. I ran the project and the build was successful.

I deployed the compiled app to an iOS simulator and it deployed okay. This is where the problem is - The deployed app open in the simulator as a blank app showing a white screen with only the battery indicator and a clock showing at the top of the blank white screen. The app is not visible.

From research, I read that this blankness is due to the fact that I was trying to open a Xamarin built app in a native Xcode. In this case, how can I convert this Xamarin.forms iOS app into a native Xcode app so I can open it in an Xcode simulator? I will appreciate any helpful input

Comment: you can't convert a Xamarin iOS app into a native iOS app.  If all you want to do is test it, then install Visual Studio for Mac and run it from there.

Comment: If I run it from visual studio, has it got an inspector that can be used to inspect elements? If yes, will I be able to use the element names or IDs in a java appium script knowing fully well that VS is C# based?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos

Comment: Run you xamarin.iOS project in Visual Studio and then [inspect elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/inspector/).

Answer (score 0):

That is not how it supposed to work, You only need the mac to compile no to run the project. You need to connect your windows machine to the mac using your LAN and just send the code to it to compile it and retrieves back the code ready for you to open it in your windows machine iOS emulator. Then you can debug to inspect your elements as desired.